# Graph: node dependency

Tags: graph, dependencies

I have a graph like this:[image]

for example I want to know the dependency of node 8 which are : 1,2,3,5 . can some body give me some code or may be pseudo code to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dependency structure is a [partially ordered set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set). I had similar case which I covered with 2 methods (in python):

- `nodes_to_update( to_proc )` parameter is a set of nodes to start with (e.g. set([8])). Returns two set of nodes: set of all nodes on which given nodes depend and set of leaf nodes. Idea is to recursively visit all nodes on which depend visited nodes.
- `sequence_to_update( to_proc )` parameter is like above. Return (ordered) list of nodes so that nodes in list depend only on nodes before in list. It is done by adding leaf node to the ordered list, and updating set of nodes to processed (all and leaf nodes).

Dependent nodes are get with method `down_nodes(o_id)` and nodes that depends on are get with `up_nodes(o_id)`.

```
def nodes_to_update(self, to_proc):
    all_to_update, first_to_update = set(), set()
    while to_proc:
        n = to_proc.pop()
        all_to_update.add(n)
        ds = self.down_nodes(n)  # nodes on which n depends
        if not ds:
            first_to_update.add(n)
        else:
            to_proc.update(ds)
    return all_to_update, first_to_update

def sequence_to_update(self, to_proc):
    all_to_update, first_to_update = self.nodes_to_update(to_proc)
    update_in_order = []
    while first_to_update:
        n_id = first_to_update.pop()
        all_to_update.discard(n_id)
        update_in_order.append(n_id)
        # nodes which depend on n_id (intersection of upper nodes and all nodes to update)
        for up_id in (self.up_nodes(n_id) & all_to_update):
            if all(d not in all_to_update for d in self.down_nodes(up_id)):
                first_to_update.add(up_id)
    return update_in_order
```